# curl email with attachment

Tags: c++, email, curl

I'am trying to send an E-mail with the following command via curl

`curl smtp://smtp.live.com:25 -v --mail-from \"***@hotmail.com\" --mail-rcpt \"***@hotmail.com\" --ssl -u **@hotmail.com:*** -T \"oke\" -k --anyauth"`

everything is working fine, I get the email. The only thing I want to change is, that the file "oke" is attached to the email. The command above sends me the data inside the email, but I want the file.

How can I attach the file to the email ?

Comment: What does this have to do with `C++`?

Comment: the program i code is in c++